# alaxos 2.0 work with cakephp 2.3

Tags: cakephp, plugins

I have been fighting with ACL for two days now and just recently i came across this plugin

[alaxos](http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0)

My question is: Does anyone know if it works with Cakephp 2.3 or higher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version that is currently online is not up to date. I won't give any excuse even if I have hundreds, but well, you know, bla bla bla...

That said, I have an updated version that I use with Cake 2.3 projects. I just made a quick download link on my server: you can find it here: http://www.alaxos.org/download/alaxos_acl_2.3.0.zip

And I promise, I'll update my website. Tomorrow...

Comment: Thank you mate btw is it possible that you can help me set it up? i seem to have a few problems

Comment: @nlcO i fixed the issue however now im getting the following error : The Role model is not configured to act as an ACL requester.

However i do not have a model named Role

Comment: Thanks for the ZIP of the new version. I also update my [unoffical Github fork](https://github.com/oldskool/Acl) and the corresponding [Composer package](https://packagist.org/packages/alaxos/acl) of this project with the changes from this latest version.

Comment: To fix the 'The Role model is not configured...' error edit the plugin's `bootstrap.php` file to change the line `Configure :: write('acl.aro.role.model', 'Role');` to `Configure :: write('acl.aro.role.model', 'Group');` - or whatever you use as a Role model.